# What is the difference between typescript's existing `experimentalDecorators` and decorators coming on TS 5?

Tags: typescript

The [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#differences-with-experimental-legacy-decorators) describes some differences.

> This new decorators proposal is not compatible with --emitDecoratorMetadata, and it does not allow decorating parameters. Future ECMAScript proposals may be able to help bridge that gap.

Not having parameter decorator is one incompatibility. I understood that. Besides that, what other changes/features/fixes are there from a typescript consumer perspective?

Comment: Oof, there are a lot of differences, it's probably shorter to list what's the *same* about them...  mostly I'd expect *users* of decorators to have similar experiences, but *implementers* of decorators have to change quite a bit.  New decorator functions take almost completely different arguments from legacy decorator functions.  I'm not sure how to answer this without writing up what's the equivalent of a point-by-point description of both... which seems exhausting to me. If nobody answers here, I wonder if there's a way you can focus the question to something more specific and manageable?

Comment: please at least provide a link to where to go for the answer?

Comment: The question links to the official TS documentation about the differences already.